# Link to Facebook doesn't work

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

I'm trying to a link to the Facebook application. If it doesn't exist, it should go to Facebook in the browser.

The problem is, when I click on the button that goes there it gives me this error:

> Unfortunately, A has stopped

I couldn't figure what to do with `@SuppressWarnings("null")` and `uri = null`.

Help.

```
package com.example.a;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button dadclink;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        dadclink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dadclink);

        dadclink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("null")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String uri = null;
                if (!uri.contains("https://www.facebook.com/")) {
                    String natgeo = "natgeo";
                    String uri1 = "fb://Page/" + natgeo;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                            .parse(uri1));
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    String natgeo = "natgeo";
                    String uri1 = "https://www.facebook.com/" + natgeo;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri1));
                    startActivity(i);
                } 
            } 
        }); 

    }
}
```

---

### Edited

```
package com.example.a;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button dadclink;
    protected String uri;
    protected String uri1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        dadclink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dadclink);

        dadclink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if (!uri.contains("https://www.facebook.com/")) {
                    String natgeo = "natgeo";
                    String uri = "fb://Page/" + natgeo;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                            .parse(uri));
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    String natgeo = "natgeo";
                    String uri1 = "https://www.facebook.com/" + natgeo;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri1));
                    startActivity(i);
                } 
            } 
        }); 

    }
}
```

---

### Edited again

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {
        dadclink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dadclink);

        dadclink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String uri = "";
                if (!uri.contains("https://www.facebook.com/")) {
                    String natgeo = "natgeo";
                    String uri1 = "fb://Page/" + natgeo;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri1));
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    String natgeo = "natgeo";
                    String uri1 = "https://www.facebook.com/" + natgeo;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri1));
                    startActivity(i);
                } 
            } 
        });
```

Comment: You are setting your uri to null and then trying to use it...

Comment: I tried to remove it and keep it and added a few things, still the same error :(

Comment: Can you post a full stack trace (from your logcat)? You shouldn't suppress a null warning, that means you have a null somewhere and you don't care (which is almost never the case). What do you mean for uri to be? I am assuming it is supposed to be a String representation of your url? You never set it anywhere.

Comment: The LogCat is not working for me, I dont know why! I removed the uri to null and wrote 'protected String uri;' and 'protected String uri1;' as you can see the edited part in the post ... same problem!

Comment: That wouldn't change anything, you still never set your uri anywhere. `!uri.contains("https://www.facebook.com/")` requires uri not be null, but you are never setting it anywhere. `protected String uri` is the only time uri is seen before the uri.contains() check, it is null at that point and can only be null.

Comment: I tried many options, it didn't work! I'm lost!!

Comment: What are some of the `many options` that you have tried? Do you mind updating your post to show what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though you aren't really paying attention to what you are doing. You currently have this:

```
dadclink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        if (!uri.contains("https://www.facebook.com/")) {
            String natgeo = "natgeo";
            String uri = "fb://Page/" + natgeo;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            String natgeo = "natgeo";
            String uri1 = "https://www.facebook.com/" + natgeo;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri1));
            startActivity(i);
        } 
    } 
});
```

But you have set your uri string as

```
protected String uri;
```

This means that the first time you click, since you haven't set your uri anywhere, you will hit this line

```
if(!uri.contains("https://www.facebook.com/")){
```

and you will be trying to do `null.contains("https://www.facebook.com/");`. But obviously null doesn't support any sort of function calls, in other words `null.contains()` will cause your app to crash with a NPE.

**EDIT**

Just because you are getting close but need some help wrapping up, this should be your onClick method

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String uri = "https://www.facebook.com/natgeo";
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

It is as simple as that, you are way over-complicating things.

Comment: Just try `protected String uri = "";` and let me know if you keep getting the same error. You can't have a null String and then check contains with it.

Comment: It runs now "Edited in the post" facebook runs on application, but it doesn't take me to www.facebook.com/natgeo ... it takes me to my page!

Comment: @Zahra, see my edits. Use the onClick method I have given you.

Comment: zgc7009, I'm lost, please tell me about "if"

Comment: @Zahra if statements are a fundamental java functionality. You might wanna brush up on Java before you continue